# Removing item from JTable and Hashmap at the same time

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jtable

I'm writing a simple java application and trying to add a feature to add/remove a school "Class".

I have a Hashmap to store each Class. The class object has a name (String) and # of criteria (int). When I add the Class object to my Hashmap I also add the Class name and criteria to a JTable.

The problem comes in when trying to remove a Class. I can easily remove it from the JTable by getting the selected item, and removing it; however, I can't remove the Class from my Hashmap by name or criteria alone, because some classes may have the same name, or same number of criteria. I've tried adding a unique class ID to each class so I can remove it like that, but it isn't nice to look at the class ID in the JTable.

Is there a better way to do all this? Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use a `List<Class>` instead? and store name and criteria as fields?

Comment: @Juxhin I originally used a list, but ran into the same problem. I don't keep track of Class object, I add them using a tempClass to my Hashmap (or list).

Comment: Are you keeping multiple copies of your collections? If yes then avoid that. Always keep a single copy of your collections (except when storing backups). If you're passing the Class objects directly to your JTable then you shouldn't have any issue, just remove them from the `List` and they will get removed from the `JTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you wanted to store the classes within a JTable I would presume they'd be kept in some ordered form. If that's the case then it would be much simpler to store them in a `List<Class>` instead of mapping them.

Essentially maps are used to store objects using a `Key` to be used at a later point regardless of the map's order.

You can store Class name and # of criteria as fields within `Class` and store that object inside a List. After that you can easily add/remove the `Class` from `JTable` & `List` simultaneously which will save you alot of unnecessary hassle by using `List#add()` and `List#remove`.

Comment: Thank you. I was keeping the List separate from the JTable. Using a single copy makes sense, and will solve my problem.

Comment: @glcohen - No problem. Just make sure that you're passing the same list to the `JTable`, that way they are both *synchronized*, thereby what occurs directly on the list directly affects the JTable aswell.